# Suppbook in biblatex (biblatex-chicago) inherits no title from book when used alongside bookinbook

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, cross-referencing, biblatex-chicago

So I have a collection of classical books printed together in a book, and want to refer to each book in the collection in italics, and hence need to use `@bookinbook` to define them. However, I also want to cite notes and introductions to the works, and for this I use `@suppbook`. For some reason the title of the `@book` parent is not inherited in `@suppbook`, I suspect this has something to do with `@bookinbook` forcing the title-field in `@book` to become a `maintitle`.

I can fix it easily by copying the title into the `@suppbook`, but then it will not be used in short format in the bibliography. If I only copy the `shorttitle`, the caveat is that no `hyperref` is produced linking child to parent. Using `booktitle` does not even produce a title for the `@book` itself and using `maintitle` also produces a weird result.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Am I expecting too much? MWE is here (I included the `booktitle` and `maintitle` cases):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[%
    style=notes, 
    backend=biber,
    booklongxref=false%  Use short for book when crossref
]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
    @book{ed:manybooks,%
        editor    = {A. Ed},
        title     = {Many Books},
        subtitle  = {Super Long and Uninteresting Subtitle},
    }
    @suppbook{notemaker:booksn,%
        crossref  = {ed:manybooks},
        author    = {B. Notemaker},
        type      = {notes to},
    }
    @suppbook{intromaker:booksi,%
        crossref  = {ed:manybooks},
        author    = {C. Intromaker},
        type      = {introduction to},
        title     = {Many Books},
        subtitle  = {Super Long and Uninteresting Subtitle},
    }
    @bookinbook{writer:onebook,%
        crossref   = {ed:manybooks},
        author     = {D. Writer},
        translator = {E. Translo},
        title      = {One in Many},
    }  
    @book{ed:manybooks2,%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Try booktitle
        editor        = {A. Ed},
        booktitle     = {Many Books 2},
        booksubtitle  = {Another Super Long and Uninteresting Subtitle},
    }
    @suppbook{notemaker:booksn2,%
        crossref  = {ed:manybooks2},
        author    = {B. Notemaker},
        type      = {notes to},
    }
    @suppbook{intromaker:booksi2,%
        crossref  = {ed:manybooks2},
        author    = {C. Intromaker},
        type      = {introduction to},
        title     = {Many Books 2},
        subtitle  = {Another Super Long and Uninteresting Subtitle},
    }
    @bookinbook{writer:onebook2,%
        crossref   = {ed:manybooks2},
        author     = {D. Writer},
        translator = {E. Translo},
        title      = {The Second One in Many},
    }
    @book{ed:manybooks3,%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Try maintitle
        editor        = {A. Ed},
        maintitle     = {Many Books 3},
        mainsubtitle  = {Yet Another Super Long and Uninteresting Subtitle},
    }
    @suppbook{notemaker:booksn3,%
        crossref  = {ed:manybooks3},
        author    = {B. Notemaker},
        type      = {notes to},
    }
    @suppbook{intromaker:booksi3,%
        crossref  = {ed:manybooks3},
        author    = {C. Intromaker},
        type      = {introduction to},
        title     = {Many Books 3},
        subtitle  = {Yet Another Super Long and Uninteresting Subtitle},
    }
    @bookinbook{writer:onebook3,%
        crossref   = {ed:manybooks3},
        author     = {D. Writer},
        translator = {E. Translo},
        title      = {The Third One in Many},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!